# VPS and hosting

Tags: web-hosting, vps

NO this is no duplicate of the above. My question is very specific to VPS and is not solely related to hosting but also to virtual desktop and such. The above barely writes 2 lines about VPS and never speak of virtual desktop needs.

**CASE:**

I'm going to upload a (small) symfony2 website soon. I plan to create another one after and maybe a little wt app ( which forces me to have a vps ). I also would like to have a 100% uptime virtual desktop + storage available from anywhere.

for symfony2, I need to be able to manage apc pecl cache extension at the very least. For wt I need root access to compile and run c/c++ code and play with apache.

**Questions:**

- When it comes to VPS, price differences are huge for similar "front" characteristics. Why ?
- Given my needs ( website traffic should never exceed 100 dudes daily ). What should I look for ? ( CPU, RAM[guaranteed?], Bandwidth )

Basically I'm looking for one or two guys that have experienced professionally a few VPS and PHP-hosting solutions, and be advised about everything I ask... and did not ask !

Comment: This site does not accept specific questions about hosting.  We only provide general advice about what to look for in a web host.  See: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/584/we-need-to-decide-what-were-doing-with-web-hosting-questions

Comment: I need to know what to look for in a VPS.